# Can i delete .DS_Store? ~251 MB

Tags: mac, finder, macos

Once i type the code into terminal to find out what is taking up 250 MB on my desktop, the hidden files are shown, i find a file called ".DS_Store"

I'm a very cleany person, so I want to ask if I can delete this file, or is it safe?

The file is 251.66 Megabytes.

---

OS : Mac OS X Mavericks 10.9.2

Mac Pro, new design by apple. 3.7 GHz, quad core - 6 core.

Comment: I wonder why it's so big.

Comment: I actually have no idea, i use Apple store a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.DS_Store` is a metadata file: it contains data about the files present in the folder.

You can delete the file without any worries, it will only delete some settings like icon position, file previews etc. But Finder recreates the file instantly.

Since 250MB seems to be way too much to me, even if Finder will recreate the file, it will most likely be way much lighter (<1MB).

Comment: Ok, i will delete the file, also when i deleted it, it recreates into a 1 mb file, thanks.

Comment: You can also use system utility like [Asepsis](http://asepsis.binaryage.com) to prevent the creation of `.DS_Store` which I use all the time.